# Volume Control on HP DV6 not working after alsamixer

Tags: dv6

Because pulse audio made the sound out of my laptop distort very very easily at even the lowest volumes, i removed it and installed gnome-alsa instead but then now, the volume control buttons on f9 and f10 aren't working at all. I don't think gnome-alsa recognizes them. What do i do??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I assigning 2 commands in that keys:

To put less volume:

> amixer set Master 5%- -q

To put more volume

> amixer set Master 5%+ -q

You can change add a custom key feature in: Settings Manager > Keyboard

[image: custom key xubuntu]

Also I have QasMixer GUI for Alsa that has a tray icon that shows you when the volume changes.

> sudo apt-get install qasmixer

[image: qasmixer tray icon]

I hope it helps you and excuse my English.